# Bilinearity: what does it mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, intuition, bilinear-form

What does *bilinear* really mean?  Everytime I heard the word, I think it should be "linear in 2 ways?"

For example, from the definition of inner product (taken from Appendix A of "Wavelets For Computer Graphics" by Stollnitz):

An inner product on a vector space V is any map from $ V \times V $ to $\mathbb{R}$ that is:

- Symmetric $ \langle u | v \rangle = \langle v | u \rangle $
- Bilinear
  $ \langle au + bv | w \rangle = a \langle u | w \rangle + b \langle v | w \rangle $
- Positive definite $ \langle u | u \rangle > 0 $ for all $ u \ne 0 $

But *how is bilinearity "linear in 2 ways"*, (if bilinear really does mean $2\times$ linear!)

Comment: Addition ($A(x,y) = x + y$) is linear. Multiplication ($M(x,y) = xy$) is bilinear, *not* linear.

Comment: Addition for _positive_ numbers is bilinear?

Comment: @bobobobo: no. For fixed $a$ the function $x \mapsto x+a$ is linear iff $a = 0$.

Comment: Bilinear means linear in the first *and* second argument of the function you are considering

Comment: Bilinear takes two vectors are arguments. If you fix one of them the remainder becomes of linear function of the other vector.

Comment: Explaining the comment by @KCd $A(x+a, y+b) = A(x,y) + A(a,b)$ hence linear. Then $M(x+a, y+b) \neq M(x,y) + M(a,b)$ hence not linear. Then $M(x+a, y) = M(x,y) + M(a,y)$ and $M(x,y+b) = M(x,y) + M(x,b)$ hence bi-linear.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It means linear on the left:

$$\langle au + bv, w \rangle = a \langle u, w \rangle + b \langle v, w \rangle$$

and on the right:

$$\langle u, av + bw \rangle = a \langle u, v \rangle + b \langle u, w \rangle.$$

By symmetry, linearity on the left implies linearity on the right, so that's why right-linearity isn't explicitly mentioned (although strictly speaking it should be).

Comment: Therefore the "bilinearity" should be a special case of "multilinearity" (say, a tensor) ?

Answer (score 15):

By [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), you can think of a function of two variables, $f\colon X\times Y \to Z$, as a composition of two functions: first, given $x\in X$, you have a function that sends $x$ to the function $f_x\colon Y\to Z$; and then this function is evaluated at a $y\in Y$ to give $f_x(y) = f(x,y)$.

When $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are vector spaces, the set of functions from $Y$ to $Z$ (written $Z^Y$) is also a vector space, so the notion of linearity makes sense for the set of all such functions.

The function $f$ is "bilinear" if and only if both the map $X\to Z^Y$ *and* the maps $Y\to Z$ that we get are linear. That is, if and only if $f_{x+\alpha x'} = f_x+\alpha f_{x'}$ for all $x,x'\in X$, and scalar $\alpha$; and for each $x\in X$ the map $f_x\colon Y\to Z$ is linear. So $f$ itself is obtained by working with *two* linear functions.

(Symmetrically, you can think of $f$ as given first by a function that takes $y\in Y$ to a function $g_y\colon X\to Z$, and then this function is evaluated at $x\in X$ via $g_y(x) = f(x,y)$. Again, $f$ is linear if and only if the function $g\colon Y\to Z^X$ is linear, and the functions $g_y\colon X\to Z$ are each linear.)

Alternatively, notice that $f$ is a function of two variables. Bilinearity is precisely the condition "linear in each of the variables separately". So you have a function which is linear in *two* distinct ways: in the first variable, and in the second variable.

(Just wait until you get to the notion of [sesquilinear funtions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear); trying to interpret "one-and-a-half linear" will give you a headache).

Also remember that not all nomenclature is necessarily accurate-as-to-intuition, and that the meaning of some words has sometimes changed from the time in which the nomenclature because fixed and present day.

Comment: + for the link to currying

Comment: "that the meaning of some words has sometimes changed from the time in which the nomenclature because fixed and present day" - this phrase doesn't parse. Did you mean "that the meaning of some words has sometimes changed from the time in which the nomenclature BECAME fixed and THE present day"?

Comment: @James: Yes; “became”. And either add “the” as you do, or change “from” to “between” earlier.

Answer (score 13):

Linearity exists for 1d functions such as $f(r)$, if that function obeys

$f(ar_1+br_2)=af(r_1)+bf(r_2)$

For 2d functions such as $f(r,s)$, the linearity attribute can exist for one dimension, or the other, or both.  If both, then the function is said to be "bilinear"

$f(ar_1+br_2,s)=af(r_1,s)+bf(r_2,s)$

$f(r,as_1+bs_2)=af(r,s_1)+bf(r,s_2)$

Comment: This is the only comment that made me understand!

Comment: @TYoke...me and you both.:-) sweet and simple. I wish all the posts were like that

Answer (score 4):

Well, the definition of "bilinear" you have there is really the definition of "linear in the first variable."  When you combine this with the symmetry axiom above, you get "linear in both the first and second variables," which is what "bilinear" means.